# Ember: how is the title of a post or article included in the browser URL?

Tags: ember.js

The standard URL used in Ember when showing a route is as follows:

```
http://domainandsite/index.html/#/publications/145
```

(thus showing publication with id 145).

I saw in live Ember sites 2 alternative representations:

1. http://www.bustle.com/articles/3358-marc-jacobs-set-to-open-first-beauty-store-in-new-york

   Thus, the article title is added to the id and forms a new URL. How is this done ?
2. http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-the-future-for-the-emberjs-addons-organization/2168

   Same question, how is this done.

I do not have the impression that the model contains a concatenated id or so ... It looks like a fragment identifier is used, but how do you combine this with Ember routes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to override the hooks `model` and `serialize` in your Route. The following is an example how the code for your publications could look like:

```
App.PublicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    serialize : function(context){
        var rawString = context.get("id") + " " + context.get("title");
        return rawString.replace(/ /g,"-"); // replace spaces as you wish or encode the URI
    },
    model : function(params){
        var partsOfUri = params.slugName.split("-"); // split this part of the URI
        var id = partsOfUri.shift(); 
        return App.Publication.findById(id);
    }
});
```

Also have a look at the API Documentation for the [model hook](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model) and the [serialize hook](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize).

Comment: Great answer. Just needed to return an object in the serialize part: var rawString = (context.get("id") + " " + context.get("title")).replace(/ /g, "-"); return { publication_id: rawString }